# ImmutableJS Map, how to iterate over a map and return a modified result

Tags: reactjs, immutable.js

I am trying to remove the keys listed in the `skipheaders` array from the `submissionsInForm`.

`const skipHeaders = [ 'layout', 'modules', 'enabled', 'captcha', 'settings'];`

```
  submissionsInForm.map((submission) => {
    const updatedSubmission = submission.deleteAll(skipHeaders);
    return updatedSubmission;
  });
```

That code doesn't seem to be working, as it is returning the full data. Is there anyway to achieve this without having to converting to Vanilla JS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**blacklist**

You could use [Map#filter](https://facebook.github.io/immutable-js/docs/#/Map/filter) to remove any key/value pairs where the key appears in the blacklist

```js
// where Map is Immutable.Map
const m = Map({a: 1, b: 2, c: 3, d: 4})

const blacklist = ['a', 'b']

m.filter((v,k) => !blacklist.includes(k))

// => {"c": 3, "d": 4}
```

---

**whitelist**

Your object is called `submissionsInForm` so I'm guessing these are user-supplied values. In such a case, I think it is much better to *whitelist* your fields instead of *blacklisting* like we did above

Notice we'll add some more fields to the input `m` this time but our result will be the same, without having to change the whitelist. This is good when you want to explicitly declare which fields the user can submit – all other fields will be rejected.

```js
const m = Map({a: 1, b: 2, c: 3, d: 4, admin: 1, superuser: true})

const whitelist = ['c', 'd']

m.filter((v,k) => whitelist.includes(k))

// => {"c": 3, "d": 4}
```

Comment: Thanks for your awesome solution and the detailed explanation and suggestion. Greatly appreciated :)